# Multiply each element of a list with each element of another list

Tags: python, arrays, multiplication

I am trying to multiply two lists with each other, take the sum of all elements and add the sum to the initial list.

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = [(1, 5, 6, 90), (9.3, 3.4, 9, 8), (8.4, 9, 9, 10)]
list_2 = [[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6], [0.0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3]]
```

I want to multiply each element of `list_1` with all entries of `list_2`
The result should look sth like this:

```
result = [[0, 0.5, 1.2, 63], [0, 0.5, 1.8, 45], [0, 0.5, 3.6, 27]]
```

afterward I would take the sum of the result and add the result to list_2

```
result_2 = [[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, **64.7**], [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, **47.3**], [0.0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3, **31.1**]]
```

In a first step, I would like to store the final data in a list for each element of `list_1`

```
result_2_1= [[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, **64.7**], [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, **47.3**], [0.0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3, **31.1**]]
```

`result_2_2`= same procedure but with `List_1[1]`

My current code works if `list_1` has only one list (= `list_1 = [(1, 5, 6, 90)]`) but my attempts to loop through the list do not seem to work. I have used zip or loop through the entries but I always end up multiplying the lists... Here's my code that works so far.

```
list_1 = [(1, 5, 6, 90)]
list_2 = [[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6], [0.0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3]]
n_list_1 = np.array(list_1)
n_list_2 = np.array(list_2)
m_result = n_list_1 * n_list_2
n_result = []
for i in range(0,len(m_result)):
     n_result_1 = sum(m_result[i])
     n_result.append(n_result_1)
     list_2[i].append(list(n_result))
```

I hope you get what I am trying to do and have any suggestions on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

list_1 = [(1, 5, 6, 90)]
list_2 = [[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6], [0.0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3]]
n_list_1 = np.array(list_1)
n_list_2 = np.array(list_2)
m_result = n_list_1 * n_list_2
n_result = []
for i in range(0,len(m_result)):
     n_result_1 = sum(m_result[i])
     n_result.append(n_result_1)
     list_2[i].append(n_result[i])
print(list_2)
```

Just change `list_2[i].append(list(n_result))` to `list_2[i].append(n_result[i])`
Note the sum of the second sublist should be 56.3

**Output**

```
[[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 64.69999999999999], [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 56.3], [0.0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 31.1]]
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you add elements to the list_1. Because then the multiplication will fail, because numpy * needs fitting shapes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use zip, you can try this code:

```
list_1 = [(1, 5, 6, 90), (9.3, 3.4, 9, 8), (8.4, 9, 9, 10)] 
list_2 = [[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6], [0.0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3]]

for inner_list1, inner_list2 in zip(list_1, list_2):
    result = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(inner_list1, inner_list2))
    inner_list2.append(result)

print(list_2)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 64.69999999999999], [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 7.84], [0.0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 9.3]]
```